# Does multiple custom post loop on a single page affects pagespeed

Tags: seo, custom-post-type, pagespeed

I have `5 custom post types` on homepage that are fetching content, and to do that i have kept `5 loops` to make it work.

Now, my question is, does it affect pagespeed and if it does it will affect SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon your page content and speed. 
If your loops are making your page slow it will hurt SEO (Speed is not the only factor). 
Pagespeed score depend upon the content. If it is optimized it will not hurt pagespeed score.If it is not optimized it will hurt that score.

To make it simple take example below:

If you current page have 2 post, every post has 2 images/resource and your every custom loop increase 2 more post with 2 more image/resource than you have two conditions.

First if your images/resource are not optimized then it will decrease your pagespeed score with the number of post increase on your page.

Second if your images/resource are optimized then it will not ring a bell on pagespeed score.

Comment: Okay, so it is totally depends on optimized images, minified css and js, number of http requests, cache etc.

Comment: Yes but Pagespeed do not count number of request, YSlow do.